# Sum of products taking k elements from a set of n elements

Tags: combinatorics, dynamic-programming, discrete-mathematics, polynomial-math

Given a set `S` with `n` elements, and an integer `k`. I need to find the sum of products of all `n` choose `k` pairs. That is, if `S = {1,2,3,4} and k = 2`, then I am looking for `P = 1*2 + 1*3 + 1*4 + 2*3 + 2*4 +3*4`. Note that product-pairs constitute the set -- taking `k` distinct elements from a set of `n` elements. I can formulate a simple dynamic programming version of this:

```
P(n,k) = a_{n}P(n-1,k-1) + P(n-1,k)
```

That is, take `n-1` elements and choose `k-1` and add `a_{n}` as well as leave out `a_{n}`. Is there some nice theory to find a closed form solution to the above problem? I am a bit lacking on advanced maths, though programming excites me. I was able to derive the aforementioned DP but could not proceed to a closed form which I hope there is!

Comment: I find this an interesting question, though perhaps more appropriate for math.SE.  As I see it, without knowledge of the elements of the set, the closed form is simply the sum itself.  I think that is definitional.  If what you are seeking is a more efficient method to compute the sum, I cannot think of any better than your own.

Answer (score 5):

I do not know if it is actually helpful, but it occurs to me that you are describing [elementary symmetric polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricPolynomial.html).

Further, it appears that this paper may be of use to you:

[Computing Elementary Symmetric Polynomials with a Sub-Polynomial Number of Multiplications](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.19.8066&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Given n, k as you have defined them:

the number of products to be summed #(n,k) is given by

## (n,k) = C(n+k-1, k-1), where C(a,b) is the combinatoric function, ie,

```
     a objects selected b at a time.
```

Furthermore, #(n,k) = k*#(n-1,k) - (n-1)*#(n,k-1).